# Multiple Projectors on same ReadModel in Broadway CQRS

Tags: php, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a `Customer` Readmodel that contains some properties including an `active` property.

Now suppose I would want to fill 2 tables with customer information: for example, one table with just the `customer id` and `active` status, and another table containing all info.

Should I make a seperate `Projector`, `Readmodel` and `Repository` to achieve this?

EDIT:
Example scenario:

CustomerCreatedEvent -> contains all customer data

CustomerActivatedEvent -> only contains customer id with enabled status = true

Readmodel = Customer class

A Projector handles both events.

The CustomerActivatedEvent handler will load the customer and update the 'active_users' table through the CustomerRepository (or ActiveCustomersRepository?) based on the data in CustomerActivatedEvent.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The event handlers of your read-side are the ones responsible for updating what you call Readmodels the way you want.

For instance you can have a CustomerCreatedEventHandler which updates the 2 tables you need, or you can have two separate event handlers, both subscribers of the same event, each one updating a different table.

Comment: I edited my post with how to flow should be, can you confirm it is correct?